# Not able to remove multiple dynamically added list elements

Tags: jquery

I have a image drop box where I can add images.
For each image there is an `X` that I can click to remove the dynamically added item. This works fine.

Above my list, I have a `Remove all` button. Using this works when I reload the page. But If I click this just after adding images, my function cannot find these items. So my question is, how can I remove all dynamically added images?

Here us my function:

```
Gallery = {
  MngGallery: null,
  init: function(){
    var self        = this;
    self.MngGallery     = $('.manage-gallery');

    self.MngGallery.on('click', '.remove-all-images', function(e){
      var imgIDs = [];
      var id = null;

        $('.gallery li').each(function(){
            id = $(this).data('image-id');
            imgIDs.push(id);
            cl(id); // <- this is undefined unless I reload the page
        });

        self.removeImage(null, imgIDs);
    });
  });


  // Dynamically adding images
  addGalleryImage: function(response) {
    var li = $('<li/>').attr({'class': 'image fade'});

    $('<a/>').attr({
        'data-lightbox' : 'gallery',
        'src': response.url
    }).append(
        $('<img/>').attr({
            'data-image-id' : response.imageId,
            'src' : response.url,
            'data-url-large' : response.url,
            'alt' : ''
    })).appendTo(li);

    $(li).appendTo($('.gallery'));

};
```

Comment: where is the `data-image-id` added, looks like you are adding it to the `anchor` element not the `li`? `var li = $('<li/>').attr({'class': 'image fade', 'data-image-id': <some-value>});`

Comment: See update code Arun. Isn't there supposed to be a `true` statement somewhere for applying jQuery action to the dynamic content? Or is that just for `clone()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your dynamic code the `data-image-id` is added to the `img` element, not to the `li` element. But the loop which is reading the value is trying to read the value from the `li` so

```
var li = $('<li/>').attr({'class': 'image fade', 'data-image-id': response.imageId});
```

Comment: Ah, you are right. When I load the page, my php is adding the `image-id` data to `li` element. But I forgot to do the same in my JS code. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You use the `.attr()`-function to assign the `data-image-id` to your image.
But In your remove-function you access this attribute with `.data()` on the `li`-element.

try to use the following instead :

```
$('.gallery li img').each(function(){
    id = $(this).attr('data-image-id');
    imgIDs.push(id);
    cl(id);
});
```

please check your selectors, I can't give a 100% correct advice here, because I don't know the html-markup.

Comment: That's not correct @empiric. `data` is an attribute and thus must be added using `attr()`. To read the data, I can either use `attr('data-image-id')`or `data('image-id')`

Comment: so what is not correct with my code ? You can also add data vie the `.data()`-function. In this case it is not display as an attribute in the html-code, yes. But I would recommend to not mix these two functions

Answer (score 1):

this :

```
id = $(this).data('image-id');
```

should be changed to:

```
id = $(this).find('image').data('image-id');
```

You are trying to get the data image id from `li` not the `image` in `li`.